# Solve optimization problem to find nxn topelitz kernel C?

Tags: optimization

The optimization problem is to find $n \times n$ matrix $C$ such that $\left| \left| x - d C \right| \right|_{2}^{2}$ is minimised where $x$ is $1 \times n$ and $d$ is $1 \times n$. Is this possible also $d$ is not invertible matrix?

Comment: Hi! This is not per se a signal processing question; and also, this is asking us to do your homework, which is explicitly off-topic here!

Comment: other than that: hint: Least-Squares.

Comment: @MarcusMüller. I'm not even sure it's a least squares problem! :-) Most of them tell you how to find $D$ given $C$.  This problem, as stated, has many more degrees of freedom than that.

Comment: Thanks for the change in title, but my suggested answer is Toeplitz. Is there another constraint you’ve not mentioned?

Answer (score 2):

Is there some other constraint?

Because this seems trivial for $d$ with no zero entries:

$$
C = \left[ 
\begin{array}{cccc}
\frac{x_1}{d_1} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \frac{x_2}{d_2} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \ddots & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{x_n}{d_n}
\end{array}
\right]
$$

where $x = [x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n]$ and $d = [d_1, d_2, \ldots, d_n]$.

Comment: true. This is actually trivial!